# Выборка элемента массива из объекта

Tags: xml, массивы, php, объекты

Изначально в xml выглядит следующим образом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Title date="2012-07-23T17:36:00">
   <Group name="Cabinet" code="10" parent="5"/>
 </Title>
```

Дошел до этого

```
   object(SimpleXMLElement)#64 (1) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Cabinet"
    ["code"]=>
    string(6) "10"
    ["parent"]=>
    string(6) "5"
  }
}
```

Как получить значения элементов name, code, parent из массива, который лежит в объекте object(SimpleXMLElement)#64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я пользуюсь такой функцией... а потом работаю уже с массивом

```
//Convert Object to Array

function objectToArray($object)        
{
    if (is_object($object))
    {    
        $object = get_object_vars($object);    
    }

    if (is_array($object))
    {
        return array_map( array($this, __FUNCTION__), $object );
    }
    else
    {
        return $object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за функцию! Помогло)